# How to execute multiple Sql Batches (separated with 'GO') in one Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

How to execute multiple Sql Batches (separated with 'GO')  in one Stored Procedure.  Like

Some variable declaration

Insert command

GO

Some variable declaration (Same with Above Batch)

Insert Command
GO
.
.
.
.

because of my insert query logic i have to add Go with each insert command so unable to remove 'GO' .Please suggest me with any other approach too.

Comment: `EXEC('....'); EXEC('....'); ...`

Comment: No, because `GO` isn't an SQL statement. It's a command that *client* tools recognise.

Comment: Thanks Devart..it works..Thank you so much...